# Как отобразить просмотры страницы, используя Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

Здравствуйте, на сайте установлен код Google Analytics. Хотелось бы с помощью него получать количество просмотров страницы (без разницы: уникальных или нет) и отображать их на этих же страницах.

Подобным образом реализованы счетчики просмотров страниц в некоторых блогах или сайтах:
[image: Счетчик просмотров - пример]

Хотелось бы получить подробную инструкцию. Как я понимаю, работать придется с Google Analytics API и PHP.

Comment: вот [эта статья](http://code201.net/blog_categories/blog/web_counters.html) не помогает?

Comment: В статье идет речь об установке асинхронного счетчика. Как получить количество просмотров любой из страниц и разместить эту цифру - не сообщается. Скажем, даже здесь есть такой счетчик просмотров вопросов в правом блоке.

Comment: *даже здесь есть такой счетчик* — насколько я понимаю, он не имеет никакого отношения к *google analytics*. вы уверены, что *g.a.* собирает (и, главное, распространяет) такую информацию?

Comment: Я попытался показать еще один пример отображения такого счетчика вне зависимости откуда берется эта информация. А почему g.a. вдруг не собирает такие данные? Их можно посмотреть в самом g.a. в разделе "Контент сайта". Если собирает, я полагаю их можно получить через API, разумеется, будучи владельцем ресурса, на котором установлен код g.a.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Query Explorer ([пример запроса](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-01-01&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3AuniquePageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&max-results=10) под вашу задачу) и потом Core Reporting API ([пример](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A[id]&start-date=2015-01-01&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3AuniquePageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&max-results=10))

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: Дорогой Николас, вы хоть по ссылке прошли? Там нормальный такой пример API запроса под задачу спрашивающего. И этому инструменту уже года 3, если его удалят — то и API поменяется.